# How to split a string in Java using "%*%" as separator, including the separator in the result list of strings?

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for the simplest way of tokenizing strings such as

```
       INPUT                       OUTPUT
"hello %my% world" -> "hello ", "%my%", " world"
```

in Java. Is it possible to accomplish this with regex? I am basically looking for a String.split() that takes as separator something of the form "%*%" but that won't ignore it, as it seems to generally do.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just split at `%`s?

Comment: I think either your description is incomplete or your example is incorrect. Can you revise it?

Comment: @BheshGurung: I'll correct it (its buggy).

Comment: it is not clear how the split should work, according to your example... maybe the example you provided is incorrect?

Comment: i still don't get it. why %my world% and not %my% ?

Comment: @devouredelysium: The separator in the input example is "%my%", but the separator in the output is "%my world%". Where does " world" come from in the output?

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer: because I've drunk too much. it should be %my%

Comment: in php there is PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE, maybe there is something like that in java too. but if it is that easy, you can work char by char, creating a new array element on %%

Comment: @K-ballo: if I do it that way I'll lose information. I'll never know whether a given string was originally inside %'s or not.

Comment: @devoured elysium: Wouldn't every other result be _inside_ `%`s? It would work unless your _split_ implementation removes empty subsequences.

Comment: How do you want to use this?  Iterating over a results a la `Matcher`, splitting a String with one delimiter, something else?

Comment: @MichaelBrewer-Davis: both ways would be fine

Comment: @K-ballo: you seem to be right that no information would be lost. but that solution doesn't seem particularly pretty, as I'd have to after the original split understand where the %'s were originally.

Comment: @devoured elysium: Not really, you would just iterate through the split results toggling a boolean to know whether you have a regular string or a `%*%` one.

Comment: @K-ballo: fair enough. from preliminary tests you seem to be right. now stop fooling around and post the idea down there so you get the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to just split the string by `%`s. That way, every other subsequence would have been between `%`s. All you have to do afterwards is iterate over the results, toggling a flag to know if the result is a regular string or one between `%`s.

Special attention has to be taken to the *split* implementation, how does it handle empty subsequences. Some implementations decide to discard empty subsequences at the begin/end of the input, others discard all empty subsequences and others discard none of them.

This would not result in the exact output that you want, since the `%`s would be gone. However you can easily add those back if there is an actual need for them (and I presume there isn't).

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do this the way you explained it. The reason is--it's ambiguous!

You give the example:

"hello %my% world" -> "hello ", "%my%", " world"

Should the % be attached to the string before it or after it?

Should the output be

"hello ", "%my", "% world"

Or, perhaps the output should be

"hello %", "my%", " world"

In your example you don't follow either of these rules. You come up with %my% which attaches the delimiter first to the string *after* it appears and then to the string *before* it appears.

Do you see the ambiguity?

So, you first need to come up with a clear set of rules about where you want the delimeter to be attached to. Once you do this, one simple (although not particularly efficient since Strings are immutable) way of achieving what you want is to:

1. Use `String.split()` to split the strings in the normal way
2. Follow your rule set to re-add the delimiter to where it should be in the string.

Comment: True, but this is not an answer, it should be a comment to criticize the ambiguity of the question

Comment: true..I had initially answered it at the end, but then edited it out...I've re-added it.

Answer (score 0):

why not you split by space between your words. in that case you will get "hello","%my%","world".

Answer (score 0):

If possible, use a simpler delimiter.  And I'm okay with jury-rigging "%" as your delimiter, just so you can get `String.split()` instead of regexps.  But if that's not possible...

[Regexps](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)!  You can parse this using a `Matcher`.  If you know there's one delimiter per line, you specify a pattern that eats the whole line:

```
    String singleDelimRegexp = "(.*)(%[^%]*%)(.*)";
    Pattern singleDelimPattern = Pattern.compile(singleDelimRegexp);
    Matcher singleDelimMatcher = singleDelimPattern.matcher(input);

    if (singleDelimMatcher.matches()) {
        String before = singleDelimMatcher.group(1);
        String delim = singleDelimMatcher.group(2);
        String after = singleDelimMatcher.group(3);

        System.out.println(before + "//" + delim + "//" + after);
    }
```

If the input is long and you need a chain of results, you use Matcher in a loop:

```
String multiDelimRegexp = "%[^%]*%";
    Pattern multiDelimPattern = Pattern.compile(multiDelimRegexp);
    Matcher multiDelimMatcher = multiDelimPattern.matcher(input);

    int lastEnd = 0;
    while (multiDelimMatcher.find()) {
        String data = input.substring(lastEnd, multiDelimMatcher.start());
        String delim = multiDelimMatcher.group();
        lastEnd = multiDelimMatcher.end();
        System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println(delim);
    }
    String lastData = input.substring(lastEnd);
    System.out.println(lastData);
```

Add those to a data structure as you go, and you'll build the whole parsed input.

Running on input: http://ideone.com/s8FzeW